# Keep getting Protocol "" is unknown error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkrequest

```
QUrl downloadUrl = QUrl::fromEncoded(downloadUrlStr.toAscii());

qDebug() << downloadUrl.toString();

QNetworkRequest req(downloadUrl);
req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::User, id);
QNetworkReply *finalReply = nam->get(req);
connect(finalReply, SIGNAL(finished()),
this, SLOT(dataFetchFinished()));
```

I have the above code in my Qt 4.8.4 application, but in the dataFetchFinished() slot I keep detecting the error: Protocol "" is unknown

The debug output is: `"http://192.168.1.1/servlet/com.roving.report.view.excel.ExcelReportServlet?file=661&columns=0&srcType=defineBean&width=0&height=0&reportParamsId=100583&cachedId=662&t_i_m_e=1376086878417&pageStyle=0"`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: FWIW  The QString downloadUrlStr is `http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.1%2Fservlet%2Fcom.roving.report.view.excel.ExcelReportServlet%3Ffile%3D661%26columns%3D0%26srcType%3DdefineBean%26width%3D0%26height%3D0%26reportParamsId%3D100583%26cachedId%3D662%26t_i_m_e%3D1376086878417&pageStyle=0`

Comment: `QUrl::fromPercentEncoding` should work. Check out Qt Docs or Sources to see difference between these two.

Comment: @elmigranto It works like charm! But I'm still trying to figure out the underlying difference between these two static methods

Comment: Well, `fromEncoded` is basically `QUrl(QString::fromUtf8(QByteArray));` while `fromPercentEncoding` actually decodes percent encoding.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?