# QNetworkRequest URL containing '?' - not requesting properly because of QUrl encoding

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, qnetworkrequest

I have the next code to make a request:

```
void HTTPClient::post(QString connectionString, QHttpMultiPart* _multiPart, bool returnProgress) {
    QUrl url;
    if (ssl)
        url.setScheme("https");
    else
        url.setScheme("http");
    url.setHost(host);
    url.setPort(port);
    url.setPath(connectionString);
    url.setUrl(url.toEncoded());
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", QCoreApplication::applicationName().toLatin1());

    /*...irrelevant code...*/
}
```

The requested url should be

> https://somewebpage.domain:443/REST/login.php?method=login_md5

but the QNetworkRequest requests this one despite I set the url as encoded (debugging url.toEncoded() prints the '?' correctly):

> https://somewebpage.domain:443/REST/login.php%3Fmethod=login_md5

This results in a 404 not found page. I have tried setting the url with url.toString() and just url, but the '?' keeps messing up. What can I do to request the link properly?

I have tried building the QUrl in the constructor like this:

> QUrl url("https://"+host+port+connectionString);

But results in the next string:

> https://somewebpage.xn--domain-efa/REST/login.php?method=login_md5

Comment: but this web page is unavailable

Comment: Well, I need to keep it a secret, the webpage is not somewebpage.domain, it is something like google.com, and I have tried the url and it does work

Comment: try req.setRawHeader("POST",url.path().toAscii())

Comment: @bits_international Alright, tried that and got the same problem. I tried using url.toAscii() but solved nothing.

Comment: Why do you encode the url with    url.setUrl(url.toEncoded()); ?

Comment: @user3514760 I was debugging when I did that. It used to be url.toString(), and debugging I found that printing url.toEncoded() did print the '?', so I left it there but it doesnt make a difference. This is explained above though.

Comment: QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded("https://somewebpage.domain:443/REST/login.php?method=login_md5");

Comment: QByteArray rawQuery("method=login_md5");
QUrl url("https://somewebpage.domain:443/REST/login.php");
url.setEncodedQuery( rawQuery);
std::cout << command.toEncoded().data(); // prints https://somewebpage.domain:443/REST/login.php?method=login_md5

Comment: @bits_international it does print it properly, and I *think* its correct, but I get this: `Error:  "Protocol "" is unknown"` and if I do reply->url() to check the url I get `QUrl( "" )`, so Im not sure if this is one step forward or backwards

Comment: the last option QUrl(QString::fromUtf8(QByteArray));  OR QUrl url = QUrl::fromEncoded( str.toAscii());

Comment: @bits_international I keep getting the same errors, either the `Protocol "" is unknown"` or the `not found`. I also tried `url.setUrl(QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(url.toEncoded()));` and prints it good but gives protocol unknown error :( thankyou very much for your time & help though

Comment: @Víctor look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156713/keep-getting-protocol-is-unknown-error-in-qt)

Comment: @bits_international I did see that. And by the way, I just noticed very strange undefined behaviour in the application: while it keeps throwing those unknown protocol errors, its like it does manage to log in but only half way because its like it keeps trying to log in, but I do have the option to log out so its very strange. Id say the issue has been solved, you can answer the question, the easiest & quickest way to 'solve it' was `url.setUrl(QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(url.toEncoded()));`

Comment: @Víctor no problem, I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [QUrl::fromEncoded](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#fromEncoded)

url.setUrl( QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(url.toEncoded()));

> Parses input and returns the corresponding QUrl. input is assumed to
>   be in encoded form, containing only ASCII characters.

to correctly handle characters.

Comment: This was indeed the answer, others that you provided did work too but this one was the better. It turns out there were a lot of other modules that missed the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded URL seems valid, maybe a problem with your webserver?

Answer (score 0):

You can setPath() and setQuery() separatly. What come before the '?' is the path and after is the query arguments.

```
const QStringList path_part = path.split('?');
url.setPath(path_part.at(0));
if(path_part.size() > 1)
    url.setQuery(path_part.at(1));
```